# Should I add a floating, fixed feedback button on the pages of my website?

Tags: website-design, usability, buttons, user-behavior, feedback

I would like to add a Feedback feature to my website.
Should I add it as a floating,fixed button on the side?
Is that considered something users are annoyed by?
If I shouldn't, which method is recommended for requesting feedback?

Answer (score 8):

Personally, floating fixed buttons annoy the living bejeezus out of me.  But it's only when I can't get rid of them that I get truly angry.

So my advice is go ahead and implement a floating feedback mechanism if you feel that it increases your chances of having it noticed, but always give the users a *very obvious* way to get rid of it if they so choose.

Answer (score 3):

I think it highly depends on what you want to get feedback on. Can you explain a bit more?

I always prefer presenting users with just-in-time feedback moments if possible. For example: after completing a check-out process present the user with a follow-up survey. Considering the fact your user has just committed to your organization/website chances are pretty good that they are willing to spend some time on your feedback. You also know exactly what the context of the feedback was. This also aligns neatly with [Cialdini's principle of "Commitment and Consistency"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Cialdini#6_key_principles_of_persuasion_by_Robert_Cialdini).

Answer (score 3):

Floating feedback buttons have become fairly common place, and I have yet to see someone that doesn't understand how to use them.  So the advantage of using a floating feedback button is that **you will get a lot more feedback**.

This is not necessarily desirable, as it will likely increase your support costs, but for most companies it's a good idea.  You also have to make sure that it fits into the overall design of your website, and that it doesn't distract from your content.

I read two reports last year stating that there was a large increase in feedback by having a floating feedback button as opposed to a `contact us` link.  Reports aside, people that I have spoken to that have implemented this confirmed a large increase in feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I think it all comes down to preference.
I personally do not prefer floating ones, 
as it takes away from the experience and may be distracting.
If you take a look at the post popular sites, you will see they avoid floating menus.

My style is to have it on the navbar,
usually positioned at the top or bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

We had good experience with a fixed button in the middle of the right side.

See: http://www.feedbacktab.org.

Depending on your Sites color scheme, you should adjust the color to make it visible.

We also made some good experiences with eye catchers - so from time to time the button changes its look to attract the user's awareness.